Any suggestions on how to avoid getting the bad file descriptor error on write()?
I've been at this for a while and I'm not sure why I keep getting the bad file descriptor error, I imagine it's maybe related to the clone() function, and how I'm trying to pass the pipe as an argument, but I'm not sure, I've tried looking it up online, but still haven't found an answer for this yet. I did try using signals still wasn't able to make it work.
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// 64kB stack
#define FIBER_STACK (1024*64)

int threadFunction(void* argument)
{
    int pipefd = *((int*)argument);
  
    char* info = "INFO!\n";
    if (write(pipefd, info, 10) == -1) {
      perror("write");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("Child thread exiting\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    void* stack;
    pid_t pid;
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the stack
    stack = malloc(FIBER_STACK);
    if (stack == 0)
    {
        perror("malloc: could not allocate stack");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


printf("Creating child thread\n");

    // Call the clone system call to create the child thread
    pid = clone(&threadFunction, (char*)stack + FIBER_STACK,
                SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM,(void*)&pipefd[1]); 
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("clone");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(pipefd[1]);

    char buffer[1024];
  
    
    /* read pipe */
    read(pipefd[0], buffer, 5); 
    printf("%s \n", buffer); 
     

    pid = waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(stack);
    printf("Child thread returned and stack freed.\n");

    return 0;
}

In theory, the code should be able to run the write() function, but I just keep getting the bad file descriptor error, I really don't know what I'm missing here, doesn't help that I'm totally new to the concept of pipes.


pid = clone(&threadFunction, (char*)stack + FIBER_STACK,
            SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM,(void*)&pipefd[1]);


From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html :

CLONE_FILES (since Linux 2.0)
If CLONE_FILES is set, the calling process and the child
process share the same file descriptor table. Any file
descriptor created by the calling process or by the child
process is also valid in the other process.  Similarly, if
one of the processes closes a file descriptor, or changes
its associated flags (using the fcntl(2) F_SETFD
operation), the other process is also affected.  If a
process sharing a file descriptor table calls execve(2),
its file descriptor table is duplicated (unshared).

But you do:

close(pipefd[1]);


So it is closed.
So to answer:

Any suggestions on how to avoid getting the bad file descriptor error on write()?

Yes, do not close the file descriptor, or create the child process with a copy of file descriptors.

Additionally, hope you are aware that the code is:
<source>:19:9: warning: 'write' reading 10 bytes from a region of size 7 [-Wstringop-overread]
   19 |     if (write(pipefd, info, 10) == -1) {
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigstksz.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:328,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h:36,
                 from <source>:5:
/usr/include/unistd.h:378:16: note: in a call to function 'write' declared with attribute 'access (read_only, 2, 3)'
  378 | extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur

Also:

// Call the clone system call to create the child thread


It's creating a process, not a thread.
